# Unset parent on empty

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Please, someone ca help me with that?

I want to unset the parent array key if any value inside of that array is null;

e.g.

```
array
(
    0 => array
    (
        'type' => 'Main'
        'phone' => '11 555-1423'
        'foo' => array(
            0 => (
                'bar' => ''
            )
         )

    )
    1 => array
    (
        'type' => 'Personal'
        'phone' => ''
        'foo' => array()
    )
)
```

In this case I want to unset [0][foo] and [1].

Comment: why [1]? There is a valid `type` not empty / null

Comment: @chumkiu guess, coz there is empty `[1]['phone']`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you want

```
function fclear(&$arr, $del){
    foreach($arr as $key=>&$val){
        if($val == '')
            return true;
        if(is_array($val)){
            $del = fclear($val, false);
                if($del == true)
                    unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
}

fclear($myarr,false);
```

you can look at the [Code Sample](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1xf-4v9), run it and see result.